# What does $? mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, backticks

I just read the comparison of PHP, Perl, Ruby and Python

http://hyperpolyglot.org/scripting

and saw the following code sample.

```
files = `ls -l /tmp`
unless $?.success?
  raise "ls failed"
end

files = %x(ls)
unless $?.success?
   raise "ls failed"
end
```

I was wondering what **$?** stands for....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$?` contains the last executed command's exit code. Which can be accessed as `$?.exitstatus`

Answer (score 3):

$? means exit status of last executed child process

Comment: -1 Not all `$x` things are global variables. For example $1 isn't global.